# citation style language - extend with an additional field

Tags: pandoc, csl, pandoc-citeproc

I produce a bibliography with pandoc from a bibtex file. In my bibtex entries I have the location of the pdf (not an url, just a file reference in a field `file`). I would like to include this reference in the bibliography, but do not see how to extend the [`chicago-author-date.csl`](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles-distribution/blob/master/chicago-author-date.csl) - I am completely new to CSL...

I assume I have to add something like

```
      <text macro="file" prefix=". "/>
```

in the layout section. But how to define the macro? How is the connection between the bibtex field and the CSL achieved?

Is there somewhere a "how to" page? 
Thank you for help!

An example bibtex entry is:

```
  author    = {Frank, Andrew U.},
  title     = {Geo-Ontologies Are Scale Dependent (abstract only)},
  booktitle = {European Geosciences Union, General Assembly 2009, Session Knowledge and Ontologies},
  year      = {2009},
  editor    = {Pulkkinen, Tuija},
  url       = {http://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/PubDat-175453.pdf},
  file      = {docs/docs4/4698_GeoOntologies_abstarct_EUG_09.pdf},
  keywords  = {Onto},
  owner     = {frank},
  timestamp = {2018.11.29},
}
```

the file entry should be inserted in the output as a relative web reference (clickable) - in addition to the usual output from the chicago-author-data style.

I add a list of nocite to the markdown text (read in from file) and process it (in Haskell) with the API

```
        res <- processCites'  markdownText
```

It works ok, I miss only the `file` value.

Comment: It may help if you could post your bibtex file and how you use with pandoc or pandoc-citeproc.

Comment: I added the information you requested above - I hope it clarifies where I stuck. Thank you for your interest!